# Editable Text Highlighting

Tags: javascript, editor, html, highlighting

I would like to create an editable "textarea" with text highlighting (e.g. different colours, bold) and I am not interested in backward compatibility with old (and meybe current) browsers.

It isn't a code editor, but something similar. So it is really different from CkEditor, because the content should appear formatted to the user, but I don't want to add HTML tags to the text. I only need to change the appearances, not to modify the text!

I read that [Bespin](https://bespin.mozilla.com/) uses canvas. Is that the right and most effective solution?

Comment: How do you propose extra formatting be applied to text without the formatting being in the text?

Comment: Canvas is an example... I don't know whether there are simpler alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ones which can do this :

- [Code Mirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/)
- [Edit area](http://www.cdolivet.com/index.php?page=editArea)
- [ECoder](http://ecoder.gmeditor.com/)
- [9ne](http://robrohan.com/projects/9ne/)
- [and others ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors)